# Where are all the places that public groups can be used?

Tags: public-group

We're considering deleting some public groups, but we need to know all the different areas that the groups my "touch". So far, here's the list I've come up with:

```
Sharing Rules
Record Sharing
Queues
List Views
Other Public Groups (nested)
Report Folders access
Document Folder access
Library sharing
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a code search for them as well, as they can be referenced in `Apex`. Best practice is to query for them by `DeveloperName` because it is unique, but it would be wise to also look for reference to `Name`. Any such references would need to be wrapped in single quotes, so you would do a global search on `'My_Group_DeveloperName'`, for example.

Comment: @sfdcfox I don't follow. Perhaps that should be a separate answer?

Comment: I think that a single, complete answer that contains everything would be more beneficial, in this case, than several competing answers, all of which are only partially correct or contain otherwise redundant data. For example, I'd be compelled to say "code + calendar", then if someone came up with something else, they'd say "code + calendar + ..." I guess we should probably ask on meta to make sure.

Comment: @sfdcfox This is now a community wiki. Please add your vast knowledge. :) Thanks!