# How to see where a public group being used

Tags: public-group

I Have to delete few users from public group to revoke few accesses assigned to those users via sharing rule but this might revoke few other accesses as well. As i am not sure where that public group is being used. is there any way to determine where that public group is being used just to make sure they don't lose any additional access

Comment: Does https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113635/where-are-all-the-places-that-public-groups-can-be-used?rq=1 answer your query?

Comment: yes, this is useful but not resolving my problem your reference is telling about where public group can be used but where existing PB is being used.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, We have an [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrQjAAK) related to this asking to show Public Group Dependencies.

Comment: do you use VS code? As that question linked in Swetha's comment mentions, it'd be the best way to find all references to your group name in your metadata.